# Will I need a Magic Trackpad to take advantage of OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, magic-trackpad

From what I have read and/or seen about OS X Lion, it sounds like many of its new features rely on gestures.  I have a Mac Pro and do not have a trackpad of any kind.  Will I need to get a Magic Trackpad to take advantage of many of the new features in OS X Lion?  What kind of user experience can I expect in Lion if I don't have one?  What will I be missing out on?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing you wont be able to use, are the [Multi-Touch Gestures](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/gestures.html).

Comment: +1. Gestures are only a part of the OS, which includes other significant improvements

Answer (score 4):

Generally, Stack Exchange network avoids talking about future products, but since Lion is going to be released very soon (according to *a lot* of sources), and having the GM installed on a computer next to me, I'd say that a multi-touch surface like the Trackpad or the Magic Mouse does add a lot of interesting possibilities to the UI.

If you're a regular OS X user and don't have a magic XXX, you will be able to do the same you do right now, you will be just *missing* the possibility to perform gestures that simplify your workflow.

I personally cannot get used to it to be honest, but I'm a heavy keyboard oriented user, so the mouse is for those "moments" when the Keyboard doesn't cut it.

I would recommend you go to the nearest Apple store and play with it for a while (i.e. more than 5 minutes). to see if you can get used to the concept of a trackpad surface.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be *required* to have a Magic Trackpad with Lion. But it will certainly add to your user experience, as you'll be able to use gestures. I bought one from Amazon (used, but in like new condition) just so I can experiment with the gestures on my Mac Pro.

Let's not forget that it won't just be the OS that will benefit from the gestural repertoire. Many applications will also take advantage of the improved gestural support in Lion. And the number of applications that will add gestural support will increase once it becomes a core OS feature.